How to save a matplotlib figure with automatic height to pdf
I have the following problem: I want to save a figure with a specific width, but auto-determine its height. Let's look at an example:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5),layout='constrained')
x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y=np.sin(x)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
fig.savefig('test.pdf',format='pdf')

Here, I want the figure to be 5 inches wide, I want the axis to use up all the horizontal space, but I don't really care about the exact vertical size. Basically exactly, what plt.show() gives me:

fig.savefig() gives me a lot of whitespace on top and below the figure (obviously, because I have defined figsize=(5,5)). Using the option bbox_inches='tight' almost does what I want to, but it re-sizes the x-direction of the figure (in this case to roughly 5.1 inches).
I have thus not found any way of saving this figure with a width of exactly 5 inches but an auto-determined height. The only way I can achieve what I want is to manually decrease the figsize until I see that the figure starts shrinking in x-direction.

By default constrained layout and bbox_inches='tight' use different padding.  If you pass pad_inches='layout' to savefig then constrained layout’s padding will be re-used so you should get (as close as possible to) your requested width.  Note that this option was added at Matplotlib v3.8 https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.8.0.html#pad-inches-layout-for-savefig

Nice, that seems to work perfectly, thanks

Thanks to RuthC for providing the answer in a comment, the following seems to solve my problem:
fig.savefig('test.pdf', format='pdf',bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches='layout')

https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.8.0.html#pad-inches-layout-for-savefig

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# plot and create figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout='constrained')
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.plot(x, y)

# get current size and bbox
bbox = fig.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
width_inches = 5  # desired width
height_inches = width_inches * (bbox.height / bbox.width)

# save
fig.set_size_inches(width_inches, height_inches)
fig.savefig('test.pdf', format='pdf')

This approach gets the actual rendered size of the figure, calculates the appropriate height based on the desired width while maintaining the aspect ratio, temporarily resizes the figure for saving and finally restores the original size after saving.

Hi Eduardo, thanks for the answer. It doesn't really do what its supposed to, though. Running your code gives me an initial size of 6.4x4.8in, that gets resized to 5x3.75in.
This is still a lot of whitespace, the actual figure-height is more like roughly 2 inches in this case.
